# Как восстановить показ по меткам после кастомных циклов вывода постов?

Tags: wordpress

Сделал кастомный цикл вывода постов из нужной категории на главной через wp_query.

Потом заметил, что при нажатии на метку внизу поста, Вордпресс выводит все посты категории, а не конкретно этой метки.

То же самое если использовать query_posts.

Когда ставлю обычный цикл, все нормально.

Пример цикла:

```
 <?php global $wp_query;

  $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(

     'posts_per_page' => '10',
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'category__in' => '1', 
     'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ?: 1 
      ));

      while( have_posts() ) { the_post(); ?>

        <article class="post">

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <div class="post__info">
                    <span class="post__info--date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
                    <span class="post__info--comments"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#comments">комментировать</a></span>
                </div>

            <?php the_content(); ?>



            <p class="post__hashtag"><?php the_tags($before=""); ?></p>

        </article>


        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>


        <?php }  ?>
```

Comment: "Если у поста нет меток, то функция выведет ссылку на категорию, связанную с постом". https://wp-kama.ru/function/the_tags

Comment: Но у постов есть метки, в том то и дело.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p class="post__hashtag"><?php the_tags($before=""); ?></p>
```

Синтаксис неверный.
Если хочется убрать дефолтное название меток как-то так:

```
 <p class="post__hashtag"><?php the_tags(''); ?></p>
```

Comment: Нет, тут дело в цикле, наверное. Он выводит посты категории 1, и нажимая на метку в конце поста, например сайт.ru/tag/books, он опять же выводит все посты категории 1, а не посты с меткой books...

Comment: Разобрался. Все оказалось настолько просто, что аж стыдно. Просто надо было или создавать цикл отдельно в шаблоне home.php для главной, или отдельно цикл в шаблоне tag.php для вывода постов по тегам. Иначе все ссылалось на index.php, где стоит цикл с принудиловкой по выводу постов одной категории.